# do foreach 5 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, ejs

i have my project with nodejs en mongoose. i want to get only the 5 first items of the database. as you see in the code below i get all the itemssmall. but i only want the get the first 5 items small on the site. how do i do that with a for loop.

```html
          <% itemsSmall.forEach(function(itemsSmall) { %>
            <%if(String(image._id) === String(itemsSmall.imageId)){%>
              <div class="position-relative">
              <p class="d-inline-block"><strong><%= itemsSmall.title %>:</strong> <%=itemsSmall.smallInformation %></p>
            
              <div class="position-absolute top-0 end-0">
                <% if(image.userId == user.userId || user.admin > 2){ %>
                <form action="/view/deleteSmall/<%= itemsSmall._id %>?_method=delete" method="POST">
                  <textarea name="imageId" id="imageId" hidden><%= image._id %></textarea>
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right me-md-2" type="submit">delete</button>
                </form>
                <%}%>
              </div>
              </div>
          <%}%>           
          <% }) %> 
        </div>
```

---

@NeNad this is the backend

```
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  //find the 3 models (images and information)
  Image.findById(id)
    .then((result) => {
      itemsBig.find().sort({ CreatedAt: -1 }).then((itemsBig) => {
          itemsSmall.find().sort({ CreatedAt: -1 }).then((itemsSmall) => {
              //render picturedetail and send all this information with
              res.render("pictureDetail", {
                itemsSmall: itemsSmall,
                itemsBig: itemsBig,
                image: result,
                picture: id,
                user: req.auth,
                title: "Details",
              });
            }).catch((err) => {console.log(err); });
        }).catch((err) => { console.log(err);});
    }).catch((err) => {console.log(err);});
});

//create the big information blocks
router.post("/uploadBig", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id; //set the id from the page
  //create the image
  itemsBig
    .findById(id)
    .then((result) => {
      //set the image in een obj
      var obj = {
        title: req.body.Title,
        bigInformation: req.body.bigInformationText,
        userId: req.auth.userId,
        imageId: req.body.imageId,
      };
      //all the thing of the obj set to the model
      itemsBig.create(obj, (err, items) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          //upload the model
          items.save();
          res.redirect("/view/" + req.body.imageId);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use an old-fashioned `for` loop, use `splice`, use the `index` argument passed by `forEach`, put a limit on your query, so many solutions.

Comment: Do you want the first five elements meeting your condition regardless of where they are in your list. Or do you really want to look at the first five elements, no matter what, and if none of those meets your condition, return no elements?

Comment: In case you would always display only 5 elements, you should query database for only 5 items. In that case, can you add your query to the question too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of items returned from the backend. You can use `limit()` method for it:

```js
itemsSmall.find().sort({ CreatedAt: -1 }).limit(5).then((itemsSmall) => {
```

Comment: From all the possibilities for solving this problem, `forEach` is probably the worst, because it will happily iterate over thousands of elements for nothing ...

Comment: I agree, but he only included HTML part and not the query or any business processing logic, so we don't know what is happening behind the scene. I just added a quick solution based on the inputs.

Comment: i consoled logged the index. and get the number 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ,12. why doesnt it start with zero?

Comment: It depends where you console.log it. It should start with 0.

Comment: yeah i saw before the if statement it start with 0 after the if statement it starts with 7

Comment: i added with a post the backend

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try it again? Also, you added backend code as an answer. You should add in the question, and then you can delete an answer.